# FirebaseMessagingService not started if install over old version of application

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app has `class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService()`
Today I discover strange behavior. When I install old version of app which didn't has FirebaseService and then install new version with FirebaseService under old version (not uninstalling old version) then my FirebaseService didn't start (onStart() didn't called). But if I install version with FirebaseService after uninstalling previous version FirebaseService works. Such behavior exists on emulator and real device.
So my question is, is it expected behavior (it seems no) and will it reprodused when user will update new version via Google Play?
My FirebaseService looks like this:

```
class FirebaseService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    private val pushRegistrationHandler: PushRegistrationHandler by inject()
    private val notificator: Notificator by inject()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d(TAG, "FirebaseService created")
        notificator.createNotificationChannel(applicationContext)
    }

    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: $token")
        pushRegistrationHandler.onNewFbToken(token)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "push data received: ${message.data}")
        notificator.showNotification(applicationContext, message.data)
        super.onMessageReceived(message)
    }

    companion object {
        val TAG = FirebaseService::class.java.simpleName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like specified behaviour is realy reproduced not just in my test environment but on significant part of real devices which updates release version from market. So, there is no guarantee that firebase service will be started **right after** application will have been updated if user doesn't uninstall previous version before installing of new one, and it can lead to a situation when you miss a new token.
To be sure you be able to get token ASAP after updating, you have to request it explicitly:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().token.addOnCompleteListener {
                val resultToken: String = it.result ?: ""
                Log.d(tag, "FirebaseMessaging token: $resultToken")
}
```